# Pirc bot "2/10" doesn't equals "2/10"

Tags: java, irc, twitch

I want to write IRC Twitch bot. I have never used Pirc library before, so i wrote this simple bot to get started.

BasicBot class :

```
public class BasicBot extends PircBot{

public BasicBot(String name){
    super();
    this.setName(name);
}
 protected void onMessage(String channel, String sender, String login, String hostname, String message) {
     if(message == "2/10"){
         sendMessage(channel,"YAYO");

     }
     System.out.println(message + (message == "2/10"));
 }
}
```

but when message 2/10 appears on chat this is what i see in console :

```
2/10false
```

I don't know why `"2/10" == "2/10"` is `false`. I tried also other strings like `"banana"` or `"apple"` and result was similar. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

`String`s are objects - the `==` operator tests if both arguments are **the same instance**, which, in your case, they may very well not be. Instead, you should use the `equals` method to check that they both have the same value:

```
if("2/10".equals(message)){
         sendMessage(channel,"YAYO");

     }
     System.out.println(message + ("2/10".equals(message)));
}
```